# Shutting down ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()), when `shutdown()` is invoked, any tasks that were already submitted (I assume via `submit()` or `execute`) will be executed. When `shutdownNow()` is invoked, the executor will halt all tasks waiting to be processed, as well as attempt to stop actively executing tasks.

What I would like to clarify is the exact meaning of "waiting to be processed." For example, say I have an executor, and I call `execute()` on some number of `Runnable` objects (assume all of these objects effectively ignore interruptions). I know that if I now call `shutdown`, all of these objects will finish executing, regardless.

However, if I call `shutdownNow` at this point, will it have the same effect as calling `shutdown`? Or are some of the objects not executed? In other words, if I want an executor to exit as fast as possible, is my best option always to call `shutdownNow()`, even when the `Runnables` passed to the executor all effectively ignore interruptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like to clarify is the exact meaning of "waiting to be processed".

It means all tasks whose `run()` method has not yet been called (by the executor).

> If I call shutdownNow at this point, will it have the same effect as calling shutdown?

No.

> Or is it possible that some of the objects will not be executed?

That is correct.

> In other words, if I want an executor to exit as fast as possible, is my best option always to call shutdownNow(), even when the Runnables passed to the executor all effectively ignore interruptions?

That is correct.

Better still, recode the Runnables to pay attention to interrupts ... or put a timeout on the shutdown ...

Comment: One quick followup: If my thread is blocked in an `executor.awaitTermination()` call and I get interrupted, what exactly happens? Will I still have to call `shutdown/shutdownNow`?

Comment: 1)  the `awaitTemination()` call will throw `InterruptedException` to its caller.  But remember that this happens when the "awaiting" thread is interrupted, not any thread that belongs to the executor service. 2) If you want the executor to shut down, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this fabulous `Runnable` that is not interruptible for 10 seconds once it's started:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long endAt = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endAt);
    }
};
```

And you have an executor with just 1 thread and you schedule the runnable 10 times:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    executor.execute(r);
```

And now you decide to call `shutdown`:

- The executor continues for the full 10 x 10 seconds and everything scheduled will be executed. The tasks don't see that you're shutting down their executor. `shutdown` can be used if you want a "short lived" executor just for a few tasks. You can immediately call `shutdown` and it will get cleaned up later.

Alternatively `shutdownNow()`:

- Takes 10 seconds. The already running task is attempted to be interrupted, but that obviously has no effect so it continues to run. The other 9 tasks that were still waiting in the queue are "cancelled" and returned to you as List so you could do something with them, like schedule them later. Could also take 0 seconds if the first task is not yet started. You'd get all tasks back. The method is used whenever you want to abort an entire executor.

Answer (score 0):

The API for `shutdownNow` method says that :

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow())